How to show/hide a button by comparing if logged by asset owner check database privilege asset owner whether add asset value is 'on' or 'off'
My asset_list html is like this


{% if user_role == 'admin' %}
        {% include 'asset_mng/admin_sidebar.html' %}
    {% elif user_role == 'asset_owner' %}
        {% include 'asset_mng/asset_owner_sidebar.html' %}
    {% endif %}  
    <div class="right">
        <div class="search-container">
            <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search by AssetName..." aria-label="Search">
            <button class="add-button" aria-label="Add Asset" id="addUserButton"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add</button>
        </div>



login database is like this , with roles admin and user
class UserDetails(models.Model):
username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
password = models.CharField(max_length=100)  # Ideally, this should be hashed
role = models.CharField(max_length=45)

login view.py
def asset_login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)
        try:
            user = UserDetails.objects.get(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                request.session['username'] = user.username
                request.session['role'] = user.role     #pass the user's role to the template
                if user.role == 'admin':
                    return redirect('admin_dashboard')
                elif user.role == 'head':
                    return redirect('head_dashboard')
                elif user.role == 'asset_owner':
                    return redirect('asset_owner_dashboard')
                elif user.role == 'ciso':
                    return redirect('ciso_dashboard')
                else:
                    messages.error(request, 'Unknown user role')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Invalid username or password')
        except UserDetails.DoesNotExist:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid username or password')
return render(request, 'asset_mng/asset_mng.html')

views for asset list
def asset_list(request):
users = Asset_Table.objects.all()
return render(request, 'asset_mng/asset_pro.html', {'users': users})

I have 2 roles Admin and User , when Admin is logged in, I want to show admin side bar and if user is logged in , show user sidebar.
database to set on and off privilege
class AssetOwner_Privilege(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(UserDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
add_asset = models.BooleanField(default=False)

views for setting on and off in database
def privilege_asset_owner(request):
username =request.session.get('username',None)
if not username:
    return redirect('asset_login')
user = UserDetails.objects.get(username = username)
asset_owner, created = AssetOwner_Privilege.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
if request.method == 'POST':
    add_asset = request.POST.get('add_asset') == 'on'
    asset_owner.add_asset = add_asset
    asset_owner.save()
    return redirect('privilege_asset_owner')
return render(request, 'asset_mng/privilege_asset_owner.html', {
    'username': username,
    'add_asset': asset_owner.add_asset,
})


is user_role defined in your template context? Django template processing will treat undefined as False in {% if user_role...
